# KeyError: 0 when accessing value in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, keyerror

In my script I have df['Time'] as shown below.

```
497   2017-08-06 11:00:00
548   2017-08-08 15:00:00
580   2017-08-10 04:00:00
646   2017-08-12 23:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But when i do

```
t1=pd.Timestamp(df['Time'][0])
```

I get an error like this :

> KeyError: 0

Do I need any type conversion here, if yes then how it can be fixed?

Comment: Try `df['Time'].iloc[0]`. Since `0` doesn't exist in index it doesn't work. For positional indexing you need to use `.iloc`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're looking for `df.iloc`.

```
df['Time'].iloc[0]
```

`df['Time'][0]` would've worked if your series had an index beginning from `0`

And if need scalar only use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df['Time'].iat[0]
```

Comment: Since the dtype is `datetime`  `to_datetime` is not required. `pd.Timestamp` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_time_slice(full_matrix, start = 0., period = 1.):
    """
    Returns a slice of the given matrix, where start is the offset and period is 
    used to specify the length of the signal.
    
    Parameters:
        full_matrix (numpy.ndarray): matrix returned by matrix_from_csv()
        start (float): start point (in seconds after the beginning of records) 
        period (float): duration of the slice to be extracted (in seconds)
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 2D matrix with the desired slice of the matrix
        float: actual length of the resulting time slice
        
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        
I have also error clear to me anyone
Reimplemented: [fcampelo]
    """
    
    # Changed for greater efficiency [fcampelo]
    rstart  = full_matrix[0: 0] + start
    index_0 = np.max(np.where(full_matrix[: 0] <= rstart))
    index_1 = np.max(np.where(full_matrix[: 0] <= rstart + period))
    
    duration = full_matrix[index_1, 0] - full_matrix[index_0, 0]
    return full_matrix[index_0:index_1, :],
```

Comment: I Have also error in this same problem anyone solve me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem

In my case, since I had dropped the first row (which contained indexed headers):

```
df.iloc[1:]
```

Passing an index of `0` would fail:

```
df.iloc[0]
>>> KeyError: 0
```

##### Solution

Add this to the end of the Dataframe you are indexing / slicing:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```