# How to access a cell in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a sub dataframe (`drama_df`) based on a criteria in the original dataframe (`df`). However, I can't access a cell using the typical `drama_df['summary'][0]` . Instead I get a `KeyError: 0`. I'm confused since `type(drama_df)` is a DataFrame. What do I do? Note that `df['summary'][0]` does indeed return a string.

```
drama_df = df[df['drama'] > 0]

#Now we generate a lump of text from the summaries
drama_txt = ""
i = 0
while (i < len(drama_df)):
    drama_txt = drama_txt + " " + drama_df['summary'][i]
    i += 1
```

**EDIT** 
Here is an example of df:
[image]

Here is an example of drama_df: 
[image]

Comment: Can you please add an example of `df` and `drama_df`?

Comment: @Marco I uploaded pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyError: 0 when accessing value in pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153647/keyerror-0-when-accessing-value-in-pandas-series)

Comment: Please, for future questions, do not upload pictures but instead share data, e.g. `df[['drama','summary']].head().to_dict()` or copy-paste the result of `print(df[['drama','summary']].head())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve it for you:

```
drama_df['summary'].iloc[0]
```

When you created the subDataFrame you probably left the index `0` behind. So you need to use `iloc` to get the element by position and not by index name (`0`).

You can also use `.iterrows()` or `.itertuples()` to do this routine:
*Itertuples is a lot faster, but it is a bit more work to handle if you have a lot of columns*

```
for row in drama_df.iterrows():
    drama_txt = drama_txt + " " + row['summary']
```

To go faster:

```
for index, summary in drama_df[['summary']].itertuples():
    drama_txt = drama_txt + " " + summary
```

Comment: This works thanks! I'll check the indexes in the future. Also, it's taking a really long time to parse lol.

Comment: @handavidbang I added an edit with code that will run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a moment here. You are looking for the str.join() operation.

Simply do this:

```
drama_txt = ' '.join(drama_df['summary'])
```

Or:

```
drama_txt = drama_df['summary'].str.cat(sep=' ')
```