# Pandas indexing and Key error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Consider the following:

```
d = {'a': 0.0, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 2.0}

e = pd.Series(d, index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,'B' : e,'C' :pd.Timestamp('20130102')}).
```

When i try to access the first row of column B in the following way:

```
>>> df.B[0]
0.0
```

I get the correct result.

However, after reading [KeyError: 0 when accessing value in pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153647/keyerror-0-when-accessing-value-in-pandas-series), I was under the assumption that, since I have specified the index as 'a', 'b' and 'c', the correct way to access the first row of column B (using positional arguments) is:
`df.B.iloc[0]`  , and `df.B[0]` should raise a Key Error. I dont know what am I missing. Can someone clarify in which case do I get a Key Error ?

Comment: You should be using loc or at. See more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035493/pandas-select-rows-and-columns-based-on-boolean-condition/48035642#48035642.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem in your referenced Question is that index of given dataframe is integer, but does not start from 0.

Pandas behaviour when asking for `df.B[0]` is ambiguous and depends on data type of index and data type of value passed to python slice syntax. It can behave like `df.B.loc[0]` (index label based) or `df.B.iloc[0]` (position based) or probably something else I'm not aware of. For predictable behaviour I recommend using `loc` and `iloc`.

To illustrate this with your example:

```
d = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
e = pd.Series(d, index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1., 'B': e, 'C': pd.Timestamp('20130102')})

df.B[0] # 0.0 - fall back to position based
df.B['0'] # KeyError - no label '0' in index
df.B['a'] # 0.0 - found label 'a' in index
df.B.loc[0] # TypeError - string index queried by integer value
df.B.loc['0'] # KeyError - no label '0' in index
df.B.loc['a'] # 0.0 - found label 'a' in index
df.B.iloc[0] # 0.0 - position based query for row 0
df.B.iloc['0'] # TypeError - string can't be used for position
df.B.iloc['a'] # TypeError - string can't be used for position
```

With example from referenced article:

```
d = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
e = pd.Series(d, index = [4, 5, 6])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1., 'B': e, 'C': pd.Timestamp('20130102')})

df.B[0] # KeyError - label 0 not in index
df.B['0'] # KeyError - label '0' not in index
df.B.loc[0] # KeyError - label 0 not in index
df.B.loc['0'] # KeyError - label '0' not in index
df.B.iloc[0] # 0.0 - position based query for row 0
df.B.iloc['0'] # TypeError - string can't be used for position
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.B` is actually a `pandas.Series` object (a shortcut for `df['B']`), which can be iterated. `df.B[0]` is no longer a "row" but just the first element of `df.B`, since by writing `df.B` you basically create a 1-D object.

More information in the [data structure documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion)

> You can treat a DataFrame semantically like a dict of like-indexed Series objects.

Comment: Yes, elements of a pandas series can be obtained by direct indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`df.B` returns a pandas series which is why you can do positional indexing. If you select column B as a dataframe this will throw an error:

```
df[['B']][0]
```